# Authors on Social Evolution, Personal Liberties and Corruption

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, sociology, history

Institutional corruption as been associated with excessive hedonism eg. [libertinism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertine). In history there have been recurring cycles in which economic depression has led to the uprising of authoritarian regimens that turned out removing individual liberties
eg. "Spanish Inquisition, Fascism, Nazi Germany, etc."

Assuming that an evolved society is the one that is respectful towards minorities and the one which knows how to live and let live. 
Are there any authors that talk about this historical recurring tendency in society? Do corruption and individual freedom go hand in hand? Is discipline needed to keep an honest system? Knowing the level of corruption in the western world in politics, mass-media, science, etc. are we at risk of going through one of these cycles again?

> "I ask you: Is it a crime to fall in love? Can we ever tell where the
>   heart truly leads us? All we are asking is eine bisschen Verstandnis
>   Why can't the world leben und leben lassen? Live and let live..."
>    From the movie Cabaret 1972
>
> "The whole land will be a burning waste of salt and sulfur—nothing
>   planted, nothing sprouting, no vegetation growing on it. It will be
>   like the destruction of Sodom and Gomorrah, Admah and Zeboyim, which
>   the Lord overthrew in fierce anger". Deuteronomy 29:22-23

Comment: "Do corruption and individual freedom go hand in hand?" Why ? Most  dictatorships were more corrupted than democratic states.

Comment: As per your ref, "Libertinism" was a "social and cultural movement" of 18th Century Europe; what is the link with e.g. corruption in Soviet Union or in some today's African regimes ?

Comment: Maybe related [Critique and Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhart_Koselleck#Critique_and_Crisis) by the German historian Reinhart Koselleck.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA agreed but in politics and morality is not what is but what people think it is.

Comment: Old political models are being used to cloak the real move behind the scenes for just plain police states. We are dealing with new problems today regarding natural resources and climate.